# HALF SOLVED: Fourier inversion formula convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have this question in Functional Analysis involving Fourier Inversion formula and the modes of its convergence:

> Let $ f \in C^{1}(R)\cap L^1(R)$ with Fourier Transform $ \widetilde{f} $ and define $ f_n(x) = {\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\widetilde{f}(w)e^{iwx}dw $
>   (Fourier Transform : $ \widetilde{f}(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-iwx}dx $)
>
> a. Explain why $ f_n(x)$ is well defined
>
> MY ANSWER TO A : We know first of all that the Fourier Transform exists for every function in $ L^1(R) $ so $ \widetilde{f} $ exists on all of R and is a continuous function that vanishes at infinity therefore integrable on any interval [-n,n] for all x, and also finite: $ |{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\widetilde{f}(w)e^{iwx}dw| \leq {\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}|\widetilde{f}(w)| |e^{iwx}|dw = {\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\widetilde{f}(w)dw < \infty $ so because Fourier transform is continuous so absolutely integrable on all finite intervals
>
> b. In what sense does the sequence $ f_n(x) $ converge to f(x)?
>
> MY ANSWER TO B: I know the Fourier inversion formula as I learned it we know that $ f \in C^{1}(R)\cap L^1(R) $ so in particular f is absolutely integrable and also it is $ C^1 $ continuous so in particular of course it is piecewise continuous as its first derivative so pointwise inverse convergence occurs so know that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\widetilde{f}(w)e^{iwx_0}dw = \frac{f(x_0^+)+f(x_0^-)}{2} $ but because the function f is of course continuous as given then we know it converges pointwise to all x (right and left sides are equal as f is continuous)
>
> c. Is there another sense in which $ f_n $ converges to f ? I HAVE NO IDEA (What else could it be we are dealing with Riemann integrals here so maybe norm convergence in $L^2$? (I know f is not necessarily in $ L^2 $) or something else?)
>
> d. Now assume $ f \in C_C ^ \infty (R) $ (infinitely differentiable with compact support). We must now prove $f_n$ converges to f uniformly. I HAVE NO IDEA

As you can see I have done two of four parts but still cannot do the last two so I need help in solving them. All appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julian Aguirre has already provided a proof for part d. I offer an alternative one.

Your answers to a. and b. are correct.  As for c. - you were right to guess that $L^2$ had something to do with
the answer. In fact, if you assume that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then the sequence will converge to $f$
also in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This in fact the content of the inversion formula in $L^1\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and you can find
more details in most texts on Fourier transforms. (e.g. Katznelson, Introduction to Harmonic Analysis, or Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis).

Regarding part d. **It is sufficient to assume that $f$ is twice differentiable with a compact support.** Since $f$ is $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and compactly supported, it is in particular in $L^1\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and so the Fourier-inversion formula
is valid for every $x$:
$$f(x)={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(w)e^{iwx}\,dw$$

For every $n$ and $x$: we have:

$$2\pi |f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\int_{-n}^n\tilde{f}(w)e^{iwx}\,dw-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(w)e^{iwx}\,dw\right|=\left|\int_{|w|>n}\tilde{f}(w)e^{iwx}\,dw\right|\leq\int_{|w|>n}|\tilde{f}(w)|\,dw$$

By the formula for the Fourier transform of derivatives we have:

$$\tilde{f}(w)={1\over (iw)^2}\widetilde{f''}(w)$$

Since $f$ has compact support, so does it's second derivative, and therefore the Fourier transform of the second derivative is bounded by some absolute constant, say, $C>0$. and so we can estimate the last integral on the r.h.s as:

$$\int_{|w|>n}|\tilde{f}(w)|\,dw\leq C\int_{|w|>n}{1\over w^2}\,dw$$

Thus we have obtained a bound that does not depend on $x$ and tends to zero as $n\to\infty$, because the integral of $1/w^2$ is finite away from the origin.

Comment: thanks I figured $ L^2 $ had something to do with this but given that there is no such guarantee of this in part c can you tell me what I can assume still about modes of convergence besides pointwise for part c? Maybe you could please expand on $ L^2 $ convergence? For this course measure and distribution convergence are not relevant

Comment: Under the hypotheses of your problem, I don't see any other modes of convergence that you can guarantee apart from the pointwise one, that would also bear any relevance to Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 2):

c. Certainly you cannot guarantee convergence in any $L^p$. You could try convergence in measure and in the sense of distributions.

d. If $f\in C_{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then $\tilde f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, the Schwarz class. This implies in particular that $\tilde f(w)$ and $w\,\tilde f(w)$ are in $L^1$. Then
$$
|f_n(x)|\le\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\tilde f(w)|\,dw,
$$
that is, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded. Moreover, $f_n$ can be differentiated under the integral sign, and
$$
|f_n'(x)|\le\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|w|\,|\tilde f(w)|\,dw.
$$
By Ascoli-Arzèla's theorem, a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly, and its limit must be $f$. Since this argument can be applied to any subsequence f $\{f_n\}$, we can conclude that the whole sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Thanks this does help however I still wanted to ask do you think my solutions for a and b are correct in particular there is proper pointwise convergence of the $f_n$ sequence as f is continuous so both sides of the limits are equal? Also we do not know measure in this course nor distributions so what could they mean in another sense in a more elementary sort of sense?

Comment: I find a. and b. correct. Covergence in the sense of distributions means $\int f_n \phi\to\int f\phi$ for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks so do we have convergence in measure or distributions and can you help prove it if so please?

Comment: Just change the order of integration.

Comment: Can you please show me? I am sorry for this but I just want to make sure I understand it

Comment: Also I know for Arzela-Ascoli you need to show uniform bounded and epicontinuous you only showed boundedness and then the boundedness of the derivative?

Comment: Equicontinuity follows from the mean value theorem and the uniform boundedness of the derivatives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29446/discussion-between-zbigniew2015-and-julian-aguirre).